# ProgressBar for perl

Tags: perl, email, progress-bar, task, text-based

I'm trying to make a simple text-based progress bar in perl, in order to display the progress while sending an email or doing a task.

Any pointers ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Term::ProgressBar module, and after each done operation i call update() method. That's all. 
Thank you all, especially Bill Ruppert ;)

Answer (score 4):

Damian Conway's [Smart::Comments](http://p3rl.org/Smart%3a%3aComments#Progress-Bars) module includes text progress bars.

Comment: Smart::Comments can be enabled or disabled at runtime too: [module](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Smart-Comments-1.0.4/lib/Smart/Comments.pm#CONFIGURATION_AND_ENVIRONMENT)

Answer (score 3):

I’m quite fond of [Time::Progress](http://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aProgress) for terminal stuff. Simplistic example–

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Progress;
use Time::HiRes "usleep"; # for demo.

my $timer = Time::Progress->new();
my $some_total_to_reach = 10_000;
$timer->attr( min => 1, max => $some_total_to_reach );

my $count = 1;
while ( $some_total_to_reach-- )
{
    print $timer->report("Doing stuff: %40b%p%L%E\r", $count++);
    usleep int(rand(1_000));
}

print "\nDone!\n";
```

Comment: the problem is i need to feed the progress bar while i'm sending a mail. When i finish sending the progress bar must finish too !

Comment: How are you sending the mail?  Are you using Net::SMTP with datasend?  Are you sending one line at a time?  Do you know how many lines you are sending to start with?